# Filter table using matching textBox and column values

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, select, filter

WPF Form illustration:

[image: 1]

I would like to filter the datagrid (selected using an sql statement at initialization) using the id value in the textbox to match the id in the column in the image (somewhat similar to using an inner-join). I need help with this.

```
      NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from central.equipment 
      where equipment.deleted = 1 ", con);
         
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
       
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "emp_id";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "emp_id";
```

Comment: also show us your code ,

Comment: `int id = 3; (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"emp_id = {id}"`

Answer (score -1):

You could use Linq:

For example:

```
//Code behind
Equipment selecteValueCodeBehind = (Equipment)dtgEquipment.SelectedItem;

using (var db = new DataContext())
{
   var QueryObjects = db.Equipment.Where(x=> x.EmployeeId == selecteValueCodeBehind.EmployeeId).ToList();
   dtEquipment.ItemsSource = QueryObjects;
}

//MVVM
public Equipment selecteValueMvvm {get; set; } = new Equipment();
public List<Equipment> Equipments {get; set;} = new List<Equipment>();

using (var db = new DataContext())
{
   var QueryObjects = db.Equipment.Where(x=> x.EmployeeId == selecteValueMvvm.EmployeeId).ToList();
   Equipments  = QueryObjects;
}
```

By the way, I think you app is in WinForms and not WPF.

Comment: I solved this issue. I called the SQL on tab click event and all worked fine. Datagridview properly filtered out the rows using textbox integer input. –